# How do I copy fields names and their contents to another struct variable in matlab

Tags: matlab, struct

Lets say that I have this code:

```
a=struct;
a(1).a='a1';
a(1).b='b1';
a(1).c='c1';

a(2).d='a1';
a(2).e='b1';
a(2).f='c1';

a(3).g='a1';
a(3).h='b1';
a(3).i='c1';
```

Now, I want to copy only a(2) to b(1) with its all fields, but I don't know what fields are in a. for example:

```
b=struct;
b(1)=a(2);
b(2)=a(3);
```

(if I do that I get the error:
'Subscripted assignment between dissimilar structures.')
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't declare `b`. Then use `deal`:

```
a=struct;
a(1).a='a1';
a(1).b='b1';
a(1).c='c1';

a(2).d='a1';
a(2).e='b1';
a(2).f='c1';

a(3).g='a1';
a(3).h='b1';
a(3).i='c1';

b(1) = deal(a(2));
b(2) = deal(a(3));
```

If you declare `b` before using `deal`, you will have to declare `b` as a struct with all fields which `a` has. In this case you don't need 'deal' anymore, just assign them normally as you did.

Comment: Thank you, that works grate. Remark: I need to erase empty fields afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

Let `s1` be the input struct and `s2` be the desired output struct. Here's one approach based on `struct2cell` and `cell2struct` to get `s2` -

```
%// Given input struct
s1=struct;
s1(1).a='A';
s1(1).b='B';
s1(1).c='C';

s1(2).d='D';
s1(2).e='E';
s1(2).f='F';

s1(3).g='G';
s1(3).h='H';
s1(3).i='I';

idx = [2 3]; %// indices of struct data to be copied over from s1 to s2

fn = fieldnames(s1)   %// get fieldnames
s1c = struct2cell(s1) %// Convert s1 to its cell array equivalent

%// Row indices for the cell array that has non-empty cells for the given idx
valid_rowidx = ~all(cellfun('isempty',s1c(:,:,idx)),3)

%// Construct output struct
s2 = cell2struct(s1c(valid_rowidx,:,idx),fn(valid_rowidx))
```

Thus, you would end up with the output -

```
s2 = 
1x2 struct array with fields:
    d
    e
    f
    g
    h
    i
```

Finally, you can verify the contents of the output struct like so -

```
%// Verify results
check1 = [s1(2).d s1(2).e s1(2).f]
check2 = [s2(1).d s2(1).e s2(1).f]

check3 = [s1(3).g s1(3).h s1(3).i]
check4 = [s2(2).g s2(2).h s2(2).i]
```

which yields -

```
check1 =
DEF
check2 =
DEF
check3 =
GHI
check4 =
GHI
```

Comment: That works grate although I need to erase empty fields, but I think the other answer is more elegant. Also, you helped me how to deal structure better.